# Symfony dynamic meta description

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

Is there a way (other than slots) to setup dynamic description meta tag. in Symfony 1.4 ? I had similar issue with dynamic title and solution was to use this function in action:

```
$this->getResponse()->setTitle
```

but I can't find similar function to manipulate description.... any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was digging and finally I found the solution I was looking for:

```
$this->getResponse()->addMeta('description', $description);
```